# server issue when working with different server at the same time

Tags: asp.net

Am working in one Website . In that 2 server is there one is a local server and another one is a main server ..

am doing porting like fetch the data from local server and port into to main server . Main server is a SAP server .. I have to Port the value from Local server to SAP server.. While doing this if network goes down or network disconnected  my porting will be slow down.. and i cant take a back up also ..

can any body help me to solve this problem.. How to over come this problem.

This is My  Web config file ..

This is my Code file through which am going to port

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Looping through all the rows in the GridView
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRows");
        //Check if the checkbox is checked.


        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            // Retreive the Product ID
            int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            PONO = productID.ToString();
            i++;

            SqlConnection conn1, conn2;

            SqlCommand cmdd2, cmd3, cmd4, cmd5, cmdd1;

            ConnectionStringSettings setting;
            setting = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
            string connstring1 = setting.ConnectionString;

            conn1 = new SqlConnection(connstring1);
            conn1.Open();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Location from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            location = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            //cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select PODate from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            //cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            //podate = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            podate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select POStatus from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            POStatus = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Discount from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            dis = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select AfterTaxVal from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            btv = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select CustName from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            CustName = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select CustAddress from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            CustAddress = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select ContactNo from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            ContactNo = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select PINCode from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            PinCode = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Remarks from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            Remarks = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select LocationCode from Location where LocationName = @LocationName", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", location);
            locationcode = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select LocName from Location where LocationName = @LocationName", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", location);
            locname = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            CName = PONO + "-" + CustName;
            POStatus = "Processing";

            CustAdd = CustName + ","+ CustAddress + " PinCode:" + PinCode + " TelNo:" + ContactNo;

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Support from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            Support = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Catagory from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            Catagory = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select OutletName from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            OutletName = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select Subsidy from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            Subsidy = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select EmpName from CustOrder where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            EmpName = (string)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd4 = new SqlCommand("update CustOrder set POStatus = @POStatus where PONO=@PONO", conn1);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POStatus", POStatus);
            cmd4.ExecuteScalar();

            Disc = float.Parse(dis);
            BFT = float.Parse(btv); 
            d = (Disc /(BFT + Disc)) * 100;

            conn1.Close();

            setting = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewConnectionString"];
            string connstring4 = setting.ConnectionString;
            conn2 = new SqlConnection(connstring4);
            conn2.Open();
            cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into OrbERP.dbo.CustInfo values (@DocNum, @CardCode , @CardName, @DocDate , @DocDueDate , @Status , @Discount , @CustName , @CustDet, @BookedBy , @Outlet , @Support , @Catagory , @Capital , @CustAdd , @Remarks, @InvoiceNo, @InvoiceDate, @Value)", conn2);

            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNum", PONO);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCode", locationcode);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardName", locname);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDate", podate);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDueDate", podate);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "PFB");
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", d);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", CName);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustDet", location);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookedBy", EmpName);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Outlet", OutletName);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Support", Support);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catagory", Catagory);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Capital", Subsidy);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAdd", CustAdd);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", Remarks);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNo", "");
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", "");
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "");

            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();


            SqlConnection conn10, conn11;

            SqlCommand cmd10, cmd11, cmd12;

            ConnectionStringSettings setting1;
            setting1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
            string connstring2 = setting1.ConnectionString;

            conn10 = new SqlConnection(connstring2);
            conn10.Open();
            cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from POTable where PONO=@PONO", conn10);
            cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONO", PONO);
            count = (int)cmd10.ExecuteScalar();
            pn = int.Parse(PONO);
            Flag = pn * 10;
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select ProductCode from POTable where Flag=@Flag", conn10);
                cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", Flag);
                ProductCode = (string)cmd10.ExecuteScalar();

                cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select ProductQty from POTable where Flag=@Flag", conn10);
                cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", Flag);
                ProductQty = (string)cmd10.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select ProductBasePrice from POTable where Flag=@Flag", conn10);
                cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", Flag);
                ProductBasePrice = (string)cmd10.ExecuteScalar().ToString();



                ConnectionStringSettings setting2;
                setting2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewConnectionString"];
                string connstring3 = setting2.ConnectionString;
                conn11 = new SqlConnection(connstring3);
                conn11.Open();

                cmd11 = new SqlCommand("insert into OrbERP.dbo.CustProd values (@DocNum, @ItemCode , @ItemDescription, @Quantity , @Price , @TaxCode , @LineTotal , @Flag , @Catagory)", conn11);

                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNum", PONO);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ProductCode);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDescription", ProdDisp);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", ProductQty);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", ProductBasePrice);

                cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn11.Close();
                Flag = Flag + 1;
            }
            conn10.Close();
        }
    }
   /* TextBox1.Text = usename;
     TextBox2.Text = i.ToString();

    string count = i.ToString();
    string Username = usename;

    string Loginname = Label2.Text; */
    Response.Redirect("SAPTrans.aspx");

}
```

this is my connection string code

```
<connectionStrings>
    <addname="ConnectionString"connectionString="DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\netnewworking\NEWWORKING\WebSite3\App_Data\ORBEnergy.mdf;Integrated Security=True;UserInstance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```